# es6 issue while accessing class variables in a $resource.query callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using ES6 with Angular JS 1.X. Whenever I try to access a class-level variable (declared in the constructor) in a `$resource.query` callback function, I get this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxSize' of undefined".

eg:

**Constructor**:

```
constructor() { 
    this.invArr = [];       
    this.maxSize = 3;        
}
```

**Class Method**:

```
bindData(){
    this.invArr = this.invLookUpSvc.getPortalInvByProdNbrSum().query({
        rtbProductNbr: this.productNumber
    }, function (data) {
        if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
            this.invArr = data;  //this.invArr not found
            console.log(this.maxSize); //this.MaxSize not found.                 
        }            
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of `this` has changed in the callback function for `this.invLookUpSvc.getPortalInvByProdNbrSum().query`. To resolve this, you should bind the callback function to the `this` context:

```
bindData(){
    this.invArr = this.invLookUpSvc.getPortalInvByProdNbrSum().query({
        rtbProductNbr: this.productNumber
    }, function (data) {
        if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
            this.invArr = data;
            console.log(this.maxSize);                
        }            
     }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: It was a scope issue. The answer you mentioned worked. Thanks.

Comment: You could mark the answer as accepted so any one else who has the same problem will find it.

Comment: this only worked partially. any changes made within callback with vm alias are not reflecting on view. I tried to update vm.maxSize to 10. I still get value 3 on view which is set in constructor for maxSize variable.

Comment: Couldn't you use arrow functions? `(data) => {}` They bind the context to the calling function. That or manually bind the context with `.bind()` either would be better than aliasing `this`.

Comment: implemented arrow function, still don't see the updates from callback. Definitely this issue is more related to ES6 implementation than angular.